# apache ant: import filelist from file and use it in apply task

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to import an external filelist into my ant build-script and using it during in an apply task.

listoffiles:

```
<filelist id="myfiles" dir=".">
    <file name="file1" />
    <file name="file2" />
</filelist>
```

build.xml:

```
<target name="build">
    <property file="listoffiles"/>

    <apply executable="cat" parallel="false">
        <srcfile/>
        <filelist id="${myfiles}" />
    </apply>
</target>
```

I'm not sure if this works. In a tutorial I read that `property` is for importing properties and `filelist` is defined as a `datatype`. I also tried to define the `filelist` inside `build.xml` and referencing it with the code above... also no success.

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks aronadaal

P.S: Is there a way to print the content of a filelist? Just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `refid` when you use the `filelist` rather than `id` - and not use the id like a property, i.e.

```
<apply executable="cat" parallel="false">
    <srcfile/>
    <filelist refid="myfiles" />
</apply>
```

You can print the value of a reference with `${toString:myfiles}` - see http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#toString

*Edited to answer `resourcelist` question of the follow up answer*

`resourcelist` is a resource collection that consists of resources whose names have been read from a file. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132426/4524982 should be doable with

```
<xslt-saxon ...>
  <resourcelist>
    <file file="includes"/>
  </resourcelist>
</xslt-saxon>
```

which works if (and only if) the `xslt-saxon` task supports nested resource collections.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for helping out! Can I put `filelist` into another file and read it during the ant execution? I have a target that first builds a list of files which shall be compiled in a follow up target. So the content of the filelist will be determined during the ant execution. I read something about the `ant-contrib` package... but maybe there is a way without using other packages.

Comment: `resourcelist` is what you are looking for. It is a resource collection that reads the names of the resources from another resource - line by line.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#resourcelist

Comment: Sry, but I had to write a separate answer.

Comment: you are answering a different question than you asked, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

I gave `ant-contrib` a try and found the following working solution.

example content of 'includes':

```
path1/file1
path2/file2
path2/file3
```

target from `build.xml`:

```
<target name="build-xml" depends="get-xml-files">
    <loadfile property="file" srcfile="includes"/>
    <for param="line" list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
        <sequential>
            <xslt-saxon in="@{line}.xml" out="@{line}.xml" style="tranform.xsl"/>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

**pros:** script-like, easy to implement

**cons:** additional dependency, not-`ant`-like

So regarding your proposal `resourcelist` I'll stuck how to reference the lines read in my `saxon`-call. With `ant-contrib` I do something like `@{line}'.

Sorry for all these questions... but the `ant` manual is not really helpful for beginners.

Do you have any book recommendations for `ant`?

Thanks aronadaal

Comment: I'll update my answer trying to mimic what you do with xslt-saxon, even though I don't know that task at all. It's been a long time since the last book about Ant has been written AFAIK, there is a list at http://ant.apache.org/resources.html .